# HTML / CSS : Reset List Padding to Default

Tags: html, css, html-lists, padding

I'm using `*{margin:0; padding:0;}` and this is the first time that it breaks me in something. **List paddings and margins are 0 too, so the indentation is lost.** and I would like to reset them to their original state, how is this possible?

I've tried this with no success:

```
ul,ol{ 
   margin :auto; /* This Works */
   padding:auto; /* This Not :( */
}
```

So how should I fix this?

Comment: Why do you expect `padding:auto` to work?

Comment: why not if it works for margin too?

Comment: Can you be more specific than "Lists are broken"?

Comment: Sure, sorry If it was confusing, I edited the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The point of a reset is to eliminate variations due to browser defaults.  In other words, there is no definitive way to "unreset" because different browsers may have different defaults.

However, you can choose your own default values, and I think that's what you're trying to do here.

A good way to do this is to look at a browser's default stylesheet (you should be able to find how to do this by doing a search).  For example, you can see the Firefox default stylesheet with this URL: resource://gre/res/html.css

Comment: The URL does not work for me anymore, but [here](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/layout/style/res/html.css) is a link to the stylesheet on mozillas website (Taken from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867254/browsers-default-css-for-html-elements)).

Answer (score 6):

There is no way to restore default values, but changing padding of 'ol' or 'ul' and 'li' it will look fine. This works for me..

```
ol{
    padding: 0 25px;
}
ol li{
    padding-left: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see if you play with the snippet below, the `initial` value for list `padding-left` is `0`. My point is regarding your statement:

> I would like to reset them to their original state

what I'm trying to illustrate and what @jdigital was kind of saying in his answer is that there is **no original state** for CSS properties, all of them are dependent on their browser implementation, e.g. default browser stylesheets.

```css
ul {
  outline: 1px solid coral;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 48px;
}

li {
  outline: 1px solid lightseagreen;
}

ul {
  padding-left: initial;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
<ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep in mind when you reset padding and margin such as `*{padding: 0; margin: 0;}`. The `ul` tag have some padding as `padding-inline-start: default_value;`.

The following these steps you can get rid of this `list-style-position: outside;` issue :

- First of all to find out the default value of `padding-inline-start` open your browser developer tools and select your ul tag.
- In the styles tab below or aside to the Element tab (depending on the resolution of Developer tools you have opened) scroll and find the `ul` tag styles from `user agent stylesheet` it will look like this [image: image of user agent dtyle sheet]
- As you have seen the styling of `padding-inline-start` in my browser its value is `40px`. Now note this value.
- Then goto your favorite code editor where you are coding and set the style of specific `ul` such as `ul{padding-inline-start: 40px}`
- Don't forget to remove the comment we have make at the start to see the effect while resetting the margin and padding

Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

`revert` is what you are looking for. It will basically revert any styles made BY YOUR STYLESHEET and not the user-agent/browser stylesheet.

```css
ol, ul, li, {
 margin: revert;
 padding: revert; /* Padding is what gives the indentation */ 
}
```

Reference:

- [revert in CSS MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/revert)
- [What is Style Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Style_origin)

Answer (score -7):

If I understand the question correctly, you could try adding `!important;` as in the following:

```
ul, ol {
   margin : auto;
   padding: auto !important;
}
```

Normally, it overrides all earlier predefined values.

Comment: However, using !important has it's pitfalls. It could end up overriding nested elements or complicate your CSS down the line. Use w/ caution.

Comment: `auto` is not a valid value for the `padding` property...no matter if you add `!important` to it, it's simply ignored by the browser, e.g. does nothing!