# How to make padding:auto work in CSS?

Tags: css, css-reset

I am working on a legacy project that has CSS Reset with `*{ margin:0; padding:0 }` applied to everything. Now, my new code doesn't need that as it relies on Normalize.css. This hasn't been much of a problem but at some places I need to use both styles.

How do I unreset my CSS? I have been able to do `*{margin:auto}` which works fine. The same isn't true about padding. Is there an equivalent way to reset the padding. How do you go about solving this?

Comment: first of all padding:auto; is nothing.. and secondly on whatever you change, you can give !important to use this one in every case

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML / CSS : Reset List Padding to Default](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561101/html-css-reset-list-padding-to-default)

Comment: @nsthethunderbolt I can't use !important because I am working on a Responsive design and thus using !important can make things really difficult with media queries

Comment: okay.. then you should follow Mr.Alien's answer.. i think that's correct

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`auto` is not a valid value for `padding` property, the only thing you can do is take out `padding: 0;` from the `*` declaration, else simply assign `padding` to respective property block.

If you remove `padding: 0;` from `* {}` than browser will apply default styles to your elements which will give you unexpected cross browser positioning offsets by few pixels, so it is better to assign `padding: 0;` using `*` and than if you want to override the padding, simply use another rule like

```
.container p {
   padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to remove `padding:0` because this will have issues with previously done legacy code. I think the only options is to add padding where required since it can't be unreset like margin.

Comment: @VaibhavKanwal yes, as I suggested

Answer (score 6):

The simplest supported solution is to either use margin

```
.element {
  display: block;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Or use a second container around the element that has this margin applied. This will somewhat have the effect of `padding: 0px auto` if it did exist.

**CSS**

```
.element_wrapper {
  display: block;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
.element {
  background: blue;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="element_wrapper">
  <div class="element">
    Hello world
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you might've meant to put margin auto on the child element

Answer (score 2):

You should just scope your * selector to the specific areas that need the reset. `.legacy * { }`, etc.

Comment: generally we set `margin: 0; padding: 0` on `body` so the nested elements simply inherit this, the above will work only if you don't set `margin: 0; padding: 0` to body

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the padding (and I think everything else) with `initial` to the default.

```
p {
    padding: initial;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're goal is to reset EVERYTHING then @Björn's answer should be your goal but applied as:

```
* {
  padding: initial;
}
```

if this is loaded after your original reset.css should have the same weight and will rely on each browser's default padding as initial value.